# How to use add_rewrite_rule function, while permalink structure is disabled?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wordpress, permalinks

I am using the add_rewrite_rule() function to modify my URL structure.

I'm wanting to use add_rewrite_rule to add a custom rule but these rules only get added in when other than default settings are selected in my permalink settings area.

i.e. in the settings there are following options:

```
 - Default             http://localhost/wordpress/?p=123

 - Day and name        http://localhost/wordpress/2014/08/14/sample-post/

 - Month and name      http://localhost/wordpress/2014/08/sample-post/

 - Numeric             http://localhost/wordpress/archives/123

 - Post name           http://localhost/wordpress/sample-post/

 - Custom Structure    http://localhost/wordpress
```

So, when I select other then 'Default', my add_rewrite_rule() function works, but while selecting 'Default', the function doesn't seem to be work. So please suggest me how to work the function in any condition. Any help would be Appriciated.

#### Update:

I think the problem lies here:
When I use this, while selecting 'Default':

```
get_option('permalink_structure');
```

I got nothing.

While in the other cases, there are some values like:

```
/%postname%/

/archives/%post_id%

/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```

Answer (score 2):

The Default permalinks, or so called "Ugly" permalinks, are not adding anything to the .htaccess file, so the Apache rewrite engine is not enabled. Without the rewrite engine, no rewrites can be done. So the short answer is that rewrites are not possible with Default permalinks.

I can recommend you to use rewrites along with query vars. When adding a rewrite rule, pass your custom data to a query var, and build the functionality around that query var. This way your functionality will work in all situations and with all permalink types.

So for example if you have the following rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^sometest/([^/]*)/?','index.php?custom_query_var=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

and you have the `custom_query_var` added as a query var by using the following code:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "custom_query_var";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

then when Default permalinks are selected, the following URL would work for you:

http://yoursite.com/index.php?custom_query_var=abc

and if "Pretty" permalinks are selected, the URL rewriting would work and your URL would look the following way:

http://yoursite.com/sometest/abc/

which is basically the best that can be achieved with rewrites.

Comment: Oh, thank you Marin for the nice description, so this means there is no solution of my problem. i.e. use of add_rewrite_rules() without the rewrite engines ?

Comment: No, unfortunately there isn't a solution. Rewriting is based on the rewrite engine, so the engine must be on in order for the rewrites to work. Personally, I wouldn't categorize this as a problem - it is more of a limitation than a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Martin. Here's a resource that will help https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15235

Comment: Thank you Anupam, thats a really nice link.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this:
function my_add_query_vars( $qvars ) {


        $qvars[] = 'business-coaching';
        $qvars[] = 'country';
        $qvars[] = 'territory'; 
        $qvars[] = 'region';        

    return $qvars;

}
add_action('query_vars', 'my_add_query_vars');
//Write the rule 
function add_analytic_rewrite_rule()
{
    // Regex:The regex to match the incoming URL is:business-coaching(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?
    // Redirect Rule :The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
    // `pagename` or page_id=45 because we use this WordPress page
    // `country` : we will assign the first captured regex part to this variable
    // `territory` we will assign the second captured regex part to this variable
    // `region` we will assign the third captured regex part to this variable
    add_rewrite_rule('business-coaching(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?','index.php?page_id=45&country=$matches[2]&territory=$matches[`enter code `enter code here`here`4]&region=$matches[6]','top');//superfinal

}
add_action('init', 'add_analytic_rewrite_rule');
```